# Getting quick replies from response in messenger bot

Tags: python, chatbot, facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-chatbot

I've been struggling with this for a while and I'm just trying to get the payload that returns after someone clicks a quick reply. Has anyone dealt with this in python for messenger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While postbacks return a payload, all a quick reply does is allow the users to send text by clicking a button. You can handle a quick reply the same way you would handle text input.